# Suggestions required: Work Permit or Blue Card

Tags: resident-permit, blue-card

I am living in Germany for 5 years now (complete 5 years today:-] ). I have completed my Masters in 2.5 years and started a full-time IT job after the degree. It's been 29 months that I am working as a fulltime in IT with a salary above 50K/year. I have a work permit (18 Abs.4 S.1) for all this time. I started with 41K/year and after 3 months I moved to 50K/year.

Now I am thinking of switching Job and I already got a job offer and a contract (above 50K/year). I am thinking of switching to Blue card. I do have an A1 German certificate with me so far.

1. Is it possible to count these months (29 months) when I switch to Blue card so that I can get a PR in 33 months?
2. If I switch to Blue card and let's suppose later I lose the job, will I only get 3 months to find another job?

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me further.
Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, In such case one can apply for Blue Card and next day after getting it apply for permanent residence permit. Then the second question does not matter anymore, since one can change jobs freely with a permanent residence permit.

Comment: Also do not forget to consider applying for Daeraufenthalt EU in addition to the initial permanent residence permit later (after 5 years of working in Germany).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Andrey. I am also thinking to go for the Blue Card but then again I fear that they will not count my previous 29months. I guess I have to try it and see what happens.